# Aligning images in bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm having problem with CSS. I'm trying to align the columns so that the images inside each column have the same bottom line, not the top. I have tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me to align the images correctly? So that the bottom of the images all match?

```
<div class="container marketing">
  <!-- Sponsors logos-->
  <div class="row featurette lastNew">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-responsive midjasponsora" alt="1496x613" src="images/logos/Platinum/image1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" alt="180x52" src="images/logos/Platinum/image2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-responsive"  alt="283x66" src="images/logos/Platinum/image3.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try give them position relative (to not change the container) and then bottom:0;

Comment: I tried putting it on either the column or the images and still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
I put this class on the columns and that was it.

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: none;
}
```